# what is active connections high count in weblogic

Tags: connection-pooling, weblogic9.x

I am new to weblogic. Currently i am seeing the active connection high count keeps on increasing in my application. But the active current count is normal and there are no leaked connections showing in console.

Can anyone explain why my active connection high count is increasing even though active current count is normal. Also please explain the concept of active connection high count. Will this high number effect on performance of my application?

Comment: Can anyone suggest some tutorials to understand these concepts?Any help in this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Highest number of active database connections in this instance of the data source since the data source was instantiated